# update and insert into table in with single query

Tags: sql, oracle

table 1

```
id            pk1         timestamp
1              a          10-jul-2019
2              h          11-mar-2019
3              k           19-jul-2019
4              j           7-n0v-2018
5              h          11-jul-2019
```

table 2

```
col  start_date        end_date
a    10-jul-2019          
h    11-mar-2019       11-jul-2019
k    19-jul-2019          
j    7-nov-2018 
h    11-jul-2019
```

Q:>  I want this process to be repeat after equal interval of time.
if a new value got enter into the table 1 then same value should enter into the table 2 but if existing values enters in table 1 then  just update end date of previous same value of table 2  and add one new value with null end date into table 2 (example value  H   in table 1 and table 2).

we need to use only single query.

with merge we are not able to get this

Comment: @cchajar- i didn't find any query for it. we will implement with procedure or trigger.  i didn't find any query yet. trigger mention below may be helpful.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if a new value got enter into the table 1 then same value should enter
>   into the table 2 but if existing values enters in table 1 then just
>   update end date of previous same value of table 2 and add one new
>   value with null end date into table 2

Your scenario need a `Trigger` to be created on `Table1`. You can put down your logic to update `Table2` in the `Trigger`. 
See below demo:

```
--Table1 DDL
Create table tab1 (
  id           number,
  pk1          varchar(1),
  time_stamp   date
);

--Table2 DDL
create table tab2 (
  col          varchar(1),
  start_date   date,
  end_date     date
);
```

Here is Trigger on Table1

```
Create or replace trigger t1 
before insert on tab1
for each row
begin
  DECLARE
    l_exists   INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO l_exists
    FROM tab2
    WHERE col = :new.pk1 ;    

    IF l_exists = 0
    THEN
      INSERT INTO TAB2
      values 
      (:new.pk1,:new.time_stamp,null);

    ELSE
      Update tab2
      set end_date = :new.time_stamp
      where col = :new.pk1;

     INSERT INTO TAB2
     values 
     (:new.pk1,:new.time_stamp,null);

    END IF;
  END;
end;
```

---

--Execution:

```
insert into tab1 values (1,'a',to_date('10-jul-2019','DD-MON-YYYY'));
insert into tab1 values (2,'h',to_date('11-mar-2019','DD-MON-YYYY'));
insert into tab1 values (3,'k',to_date('19-jul-2019','DD-MON-YYYY'));
insert into tab1 values (4,'j',to_date('07-nov-2019','DD-MON-YYYY'));
insert into tab1 values (5,'h',to_date('11-jul-2019','DD-MON-YYYY'));

Commit;

SQL> select * from tab1;

    ID P TIME_STAM
   ---------- - ---------
     1 a 10-JUL-19
     3 k 19-JUL-19
     4 j 07-NOV-19
     2 h 11-MAR-19
     5 h 11-JUL-19

 SQL> select * from tab2;

      C START_DAT END_DATE
      - --------- ---------
      a 10-JUL-19
      k 19-JUL-19
      j 07-NOV-19
      h 11-MAR-19 11-JUL-19
      h 11-JUL-19
```

Comment: no, it is partially correct.   i want if the value already exists then just add new row to table as well as update end date with new start date.        please suggest if it is possible with SQL query, no plsql block

Comment: @lakshayGulati You can modify the trigger as per you need, And also its not possible to do it using SQL query. Anyways i have updated the code. Run and validate.